# remove duplicate from nested JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

How can I use PHP to remove a duplicate from JSON?

```
{
  "keyword": [{
    "consultion": [{
      "title": "\u0645\u062f\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0636",
      "content": "\u0645\u0627 \u0645\u0639\u062f\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0642\u0627\u0621 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0642\u064a\u062f \u0627\u0644\u062d\u064a\u0627\u0629 \u0628\u0639\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0635\u0627\u0628\u0629 \u0628\u0645\u0631\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0644\u0632\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0645\u0631\u061f",
      "id": "1"
    }]
  }, {
    "consultion": [{
      "title": " \u0645\u062a\u0644\u0627\u0632\u0645\u0629 \u063a\u0631\u0648\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0645\u0633",
      "content": " \u0645\u0627 \"\u0645\u062a\u0644\u0627\u0632\u0645\u0629 \u063a\u0631\u0648\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0645\u0633\" \u0627\u0644\u062a\u064a \u0642\u062f \u064a\u0639\u0627\u0646\u064a \u0645\u0646\u0647\u0627 \u0645\u0631\u064a\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0644\u0632\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0645\u0631\u061f",
      "id": "2"
    }]
  }, {
    "consultion": [{
      "title": "\u0645\u062f\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0636",
      "content": "\u0645\u0627 \u0645\u0639\u062f\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0642\u0627\u0621 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0642\u064a\u062f \u0627\u0644\u062d\u064a\u0627\u0629 \u0628\u0639\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0635\u0627\u0628\u0629 \u0628\u0645\u0631\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0644\u0632\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0645\u0631\u061f",
      "id": "1"
    }]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just decode the JSON string, run an [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) on the keywords array and encode back into JSON:

```
// Decode JSON into an array
$str = '{"keyword":[{"consultion":[{"title":"\u0645\u062f\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0636","content":"\u0645\u0627 \u0645\u0639\u062f\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0642\u0627\u0621 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0642\u064a\u062f \u0627\u0644\u062d\u064a\u0627\u0629 \u0628\u0639\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0635\u0627\u0628\u0629 \u0628\u0645\u0631\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0644\u0632\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0645\u0631\u061f","id":"1"}]},{"consultion":[{"title":" \u0645\u062a\u0644\u0627\u0632\u0645\u0629 \u063a\u0631\u0648\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0645\u0633","content":" \u0645\u0627 \"\u0645\u062a\u0644\u0627\u0632\u0645\u0629 \u063a\u0631\u0648\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0645\u0633\" \u0627\u0644\u062a\u064a \u0642\u062f \u064a\u0639\u0627\u0646\u064a \u0645\u0646\u0647\u0627 \u0645\u0631\u064a\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0644\u0632\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0645\u0631\u061f","id":"2"}]},{"consultion":[{"title":"\u0645\u062f\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0636","content":"\u0645\u0627 \u0645\u0639\u062f\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0642\u0627\u0621 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0642\u064a\u062f \u0627\u0644\u062d\u064a\u0627\u0629 \u0628\u0639\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0635\u0627\u0628\u0629 \u0628\u0645\u0631\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0644\u0632\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0645\u0631\u061f","id":"1"}]}]}';
$array = json_decode($str, true);

// Remove duplicates from 'keyword' array
$array['keyword'] = array_unique($array['keyword'], SORT_REGULAR);

// Encode back into JSON
$json = json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json;
```

Output:

```
{
    "keyword": [
        {
            "consultion": [
                {
                    "title": "\u0645\u062f\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0636",
                    "content": "\u0645\u0627 \u0645\u0639\u062f\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0642\u0627\u0621 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0642\u064a\u062f \u0627\u0644\u062d\u064a\u0627\u0629 \u0628\u0639\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0635\u0627\u0628\u0629 \u0628\u0645\u0631\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0644\u0632\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0645\u0631\u061f",
                    "id": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "consultion": [
                {
                    "title": " \u0645\u062a\u0644\u0627\u0632\u0645\u0629 \u063a\u0631\u0648\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0645\u0633",
                    "content": " \u0645\u0627 \"\u0645\u062a\u0644\u0627\u0632\u0645\u0629 \u063a\u0631\u0648\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0645\u0633\" \u0627\u0644\u062a\u064a \u0642\u062f \u064a\u0639\u0627\u0646\u064a \u0645\u0646\u0647\u0627 \u0645\u0631\u064a\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0644\u0632\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0645\u0631\u061f",
                    "id": "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode('{"keyword":[{"consultion":[{"title":"\u0645\u062f\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0636","content":"\u0645\u0627 \u0645\u0639\u062f\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0642\u0627\u0621 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0642\u064a\u062f \u0627\u0644\u062d\u064a\u0627\u0629 \u0628\u0639\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0635\u0627\u0628\u0629 \u0628\u0645\u0631\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0644\u0632\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0645\u0631\u061f","id":"1"}]},{"consultion":[{"title":" \u0645\u062a\u0644\u0627\u0632\u0645\u0629 \u063a\u0631\u0648\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0645\u0633","content":" \u0645\u0627 \"\u0645\u062a\u0644\u0627\u0632\u0645\u0629 \u063a\u0631\u0648\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0645\u0633\" \u0627\u0644\u062a\u064a \u0642\u062f \u064a\u0639\u0627\u0646\u064a \u0645\u0646\u0647\u0627 \u0645\u0631\u064a\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0644\u0632\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0645\u0631\u061f","id":"2"}]},{"consultion":[{"title":"\u0645\u062f\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0636","content":"\u0645\u0627 \u0645\u0639\u062f\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0642\u0627\u0621 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0642\u064a\u062f \u0627\u0644\u062d\u064a\u0627\u0629 \u0628\u0639\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0635\u0627\u0628\u0629 \u0628\u0645\u0631\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0644\u0632\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0645\u0631\u061f","id":"1"}]}]}');
    $data = $data->keyword[0];

    $new_data['title'] = $data->title;
    $new_data['consultion'] = $data->consultion;
    echo json_encode($new_data);
?>
```

PS:

```
<?php

    $data = json_decode('{"keyword":[{"consultion":[{"title":"\u0645\u062f\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0636","content":"\u0645\u0627 \u0645\u0639\u062f\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0642\u0627\u0621 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0642\u064a\u062f \u0627\u0644\u062d\u064a\u0627\u0629 \u0628\u0639\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0635\u0627\u0628\u0629 \u0628\u0645\u0631\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0644\u0632\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0645\u0631\u061f","id":"1"}]},{"consultion":[{"title":" \u0645\u062a\u0644\u0627\u0632\u0645\u0629 \u063a\u0631\u0648\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0645\u0633","content":" \u0645\u0627 \"\u0645\u062a\u0644\u0627\u0632\u0645\u0629 \u063a\u0631\u0648\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0645\u0633\" \u0627\u0644\u062a\u064a \u0642\u062f \u064a\u0639\u0627\u0646\u064a \u0645\u0646\u0647\u0627 \u0645\u0631\u064a\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0644\u0632\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0645\u0631\u061f","id":"2"}]},{"consultion":[{"title":"\u0645\u062f\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0636","content":"\u0645\u0627 \u0645\u0639\u062f\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0642\u0627\u0621 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0642\u064a\u062f \u0627\u0644\u062d\u064a\u0627\u0629 \u0628\u0639\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0635\u0627\u0628\u0629 \u0628\u0645\u0631\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0644\u0632\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0645\u0631\u061f","id":"1"}]}]}');
    $keywords = $data->keyword;

    $new_data = array();

    foreach ($keywords as $consultion) {

        if (array_search($consultion, $new_data) === FALSE) {
            $new_data[] = $consultion;
        }
    }

    print_r($new_data);
    //echo json_encode($new_data);

    /******************** Example **********************************/
    echo "\r\n\r\n";
    $data = array();
    $data['consultion'][] = array('title' => 'a', 'id' => 1);
    $data['consultion'][] = array('title' => 'b', 'id' => 2);
    $data['consultion'][] = array('title' => 'a', 'id' => 1); //duplicated

    $encoded = json_encode($data);
    $data = json_decode($encoded);


    $new_data = array();

    foreach ($data->consultion as $obj) {

        if (array_search($obj, $new_data) === FALSE) {
            $new_data[] = $obj;
        }
    }

    print_r($new_data);
    //echo json_encode($new_data);

?>
```

Comment: any clarification please , i have array keyword with sub array consultion

Comment: Look at the new answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
// copy them into anther array with check if content is taken before or not 

$array = json_decode(json, TRUE);
// [["title"=>"", "content"=>""],["title"=>"", "content"=>""]]
$arr = json_decode('{"keyword":[{"consultion":[{"title":"\u0645\u062f\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0636","content":"\u0645\u0627 \u0645\u0639\u062f\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0642\u0627\u0621 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0642\u064a\u062f \u0627\u0644\u062d\u064a\u0627\u0629 \u0628\u0639\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0635\u0627\u0628\u0629 \u0628\u0645\u0631\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0644\u0632\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0645\u0631\u061f","id":"1"}]},{"consultion":[{"title":" \u0645\u062a\u0644\u0627\u0632\u0645\u0629 \u063a\u0631\u0648\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0645\u0633","content":" \u0645\u0627 \"\u0645\u062a\u0644\u0627\u0632\u0645\u0629 \u063a\u0631\u0648\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0634\u0645\u0633\" \u0627\u0644\u062a\u064a \u0642\u062f \u064a\u0639\u0627\u0646\u064a \u0645\u0646\u0647\u0627 \u0645\u0631\u064a\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0644\u0632\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0645\u0631\u061f","id":"2"}]},{"consultion":[{"title":"\u0645\u062f\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0636","content":"\u0645\u0627 \u0645\u0639\u062f\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0642\u0627\u0621 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0642\u064a\u062f \u0627\u0644\u062d\u064a\u0627\u0629 \u0628\u0639\u062f \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0635\u0627\u0628\u0629 \u0628\u0645\u0631\u0636 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0644\u0632\u0647\u0627\u064a\u0645\u0631\u061f","id":"1"}]}]} ',true);
$tmp = array();
foreach ($arr["keyword"] as $item){
   if(in_array( $item, $tmp  )  ){ continue; }
   $tmp[] = $item;
}

print_r($tmp);
 // or 
json_encode($tmp);
```